# Quickblox: How to use pagination in fetching custom objects using Web SDK

Tags: javascript, web, sdk, pagination, quickblox

I am making a quick web report for my team to view selected application data using Quickblox Web SDK.

I am able to fetch users data and also *some* custom objects data up to 100 objects. The question is, how to fetch more than 100 custom objects e.g. use pagination?

With users query, I am using following (this works fine):

```
var params = {};
{params.perPage = 100;}
{params.pageNo = page;}
QB.users.listUsers(params, function(err,result) { ... }
```

But, how to do the same when fetching custom objects using Quickblox Web SDK (Javascript) library?

Any tips or recommendations are appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay.. Sometimes just posting a SO question gets brains working better.

So, answering my own question in case someone else has a brain bump.. :)

Simple way to create pagination with custom object fetch is to use filters and *skip* parameter as stated in:
http://quickblox.com/developers/Custom_Objects#Parameters

Full query would be something like this:
    var filter = {skip: skipCount};
    QB.data.list("CUSTOM_CLASS_NAME", filter, function(err, result) { ... }